# Account hacked, no access to phone number need sent to new phone number or email

Tags: facebook

My Facebook account was hacked, and it is temporarily unavailable, and it is trying to send a text to my phone number for a security code, only I no longer have access to the phone number either. Is there anyway to have the security code sent via email or text to another phone number?

Answer (score 2):

See if this page to [securing your hacked account](http://www.facebook.com/hacked) will work.

Otherwise try going to the page in question and clicking Report > This is my old account