# How can I recover a hacked FB account with no access to my old email?

Tags: facebook, hacked

First, I found this old question - [Account hacked, no access to phone number need sent to new phone number or email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18680/account-hacked-no-access-to-phone-number-need-sent-to-new-phone-number-or-email) but the answer there is either no longer relevant or does not solve my specific problem.

My wife's old Hotmail was compromised after not being used for several years. Unfortunately attempts to recover it failed, probably because she hasn't used it for so long and it had no personal data to identify her. Details below.

Using that email, they hacked her FB account. FB does have a lot of personal data about her and we would like to secure the account, but it's proving troublesome.

Using `www.facebook.com/hacked` ends when we select that we no longer have access to the email. She also opened a new account and reported the old one as impersonating her, and also as her old account asking to close it, but as usual she was pointed to `www.facebook.com/hacked`.

At some point the hacker added a phone number, and then suddenly when using the hacked interface we got a new option, to submit a photo ID and a new email. We were excited, but then met an endless army of robots... They turned us back to `facebook.com/hacked`, which is how we reached them in the first place. Then they asked for a photo ID, which we already provided, but we provided it again. Then they sent us back to `facebook.com/hacked` once again. It was like they read one word of our message and selected a random response.

Does anyone know of any way we can contact a human being that will actually look into this?

The hacker now has access to all her personal data and friends. I know she was careless by not protecting both her email and Facebook account, but there must be something we can do, at least to get them to close this account.